# bringing down the target sdk and error syncing

Tags: android

In android studio, I am compiling against version 26.
However I decided to change the compile and target sdk to v23 but the issue is that I keep getting the error below upon sync gradle

Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.

How can I get rid of it? It does not even point to lines of code
Thanks

Comment: change the button style

Comment: can you show your gradle file?

Comment: Post your app level build.gradle file.

Comment: I will post it as soon as I get home

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have different version of compileSdkVersion and support library version. If you want to compile against version 23, you need to change your support library to version 23 too.

Your `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support library` should use the same version.

Comment: All of them are synced but I will check the build tool